# Input type text binding dynamically in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a simple app which adds the textbox value to listbox when enter key is pressed in textbox.
Here is my html code

```
<input type="text" value="{{ myText }}" (keypress)="keyEvent($event)"  /> 
<select multiple="multiple" >
  <option *ngFor="let item of itemsList">
    {{item}} 
  </option>
</select>
```

here is my typescript component code

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = `hello world app !`;
  myText ='';
  itemsList = [];constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  keyEvent(event)
  {
    if(event.keyCode === 13)
    {
      event.preventDefault(); // Otherwise the form will be submitted
      this.itemsList.push(this.myText);
    }
  }
```

myText value is not getting updated . the value is always null.

Please help to figure out what is that i am missing while binding myText.

Answer (score 9):

It's not updating because you need **TWO WAY data binding** via `ngModel`:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myText" (keypress)="keyEvent($event)" />
```

For more info: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: after adding [(ngModel)]="myText" html page goes blank :(

Comment: @Comercial Suicide No errors .. when i remove the outer braces atleast the screen is visible but still the binding doesnt happen ----------- like this.(ngModel)="myText"

Comment: @Peekay, the `ngModel`s two way binding will work only with "banana in box" notation `[()]`. Sorry, I can't really say why you're getting the blank page  when using `[(ngModel)]` without live example =(

Comment: @Peekay, what is the `p` attribute on your input?

Comment: @Peekay you need to add imports in component.ts  import { NgModel , NgForm } from '@angular/forms';